# React Native Facebook login, can't find variable Document

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add Facebook User Authentication, for Graphcool. For React, they have provided a snippet to initialize the SDK. However, since I am using React Native, "document" is not a variable. There is no tutorial for React Native on this. Any workarounds?

```
_initializeFacebookSDK() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      version    : FACEBOOK_API_VERSION // use Facebook API version 2.10
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [Facebook's FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) library for react-native and follow the installation and initialization implementations provided by them.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk